# Best way to save jsonb field in Rails using form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I want to directly edit `jsonb` field of my model. I'm using text-area field to display the jsonb contents and then transform it to the hash using `:attr_accessor` to create a 'fake' field. Is there a better, rails-way to achieve it?

So my model has `config` field and looks like this:

```
class PrizeDefinition < ApplicationRecord
  # TODO: find better way to handle this
  attr_accessor :config_str

  after_initialize :set_config_str

  def set_config_str
    self.config_str = config.to_json
  end
end
```

My form looks like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :config_str, t('admin.attributes.config') %>
      <%= f.text_area :config_str, class: 'form-control', rows: 5 %>
    </div>
```

And in controller I explicitly update the field like this:

```
def update
  item = PrizeDefinition.find(params[:id])
  item.update(prize_definition_params)
  # TODO: pass config and prize definition params in single request
  item.update(config: JSON.parse(params.require(:prize_definition)[:config_str]))
  redirect_to admin_prize_definition_path(item)
end
```

My questions is:
1. How can I make the transformation implicit (using serializers)?
2. Is there any better way to save jsonb fields?

Answer (score 0):

if the field you want to be stored as JSON is a text field, you can add the following line to the model and rails will handle packing and unpacking the JSON each time on accessing the column:
`serialize :config_str, JSON`

Comment: Nah, it's not the thing I'm looking for. If I use 'fake' model attribute I still have to update it manually. What I'm looking for is to work directly with jsonb field.